# How to hide a row in ssrs using a multi select parameter

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I need to be able to conditionally hide a row in SSRS 2005 based on a Multi Select Parameter. I need to be able to hide the row if the multi parameter = "CS", but if the Multi select Parameter is "CS" and "Sales" then I need to see the row.
I've tried this formula:

```
=IIf((Parameters!Level_4.Value(0) = "CS"
And Parameters!Level_4.Value(0) = "Sales"),false ,True)
=IIF((Parameters!Level_4.Value(0) = "CS"), True, False)
```

But it does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=Switch(
Array.IndexOf(Parameters!Level_4.Value, "CS")>-1 AND
Array.IndexOf(Parameters!Level_4.Value, "Sales")>-1,false,
Array.IndexOf(Parameters!Level_4.Value, "CS")>-1,true
)
```

Note multivalued parameters can contain one or multiple values which are stored in an array data type. So if you select a value in your report it will be stored in the `0` index of the array, if you select one more value it will be stored in the `1` index and so on.

Example: `"CS"` value is stored in `Level_4.Value(0)` and `"Sales"` is stored in `Level_4.Value(1)`.

The expression I proposed will check if both values were selected and return `true` in that case, otherwise if only `"CS"` is selected it will return `false`.

**UPDATE:** Alternative to IndexOf support

```
=Switch(
InStr(Join(Parameters!Level_4.Value, ","),"CS")>0 AND
InStr(Join(Parameters!Level_4.Value, ","),"Sales")>0,false,
InStr(Join(Parameters!Level_4.Value, ","),"CS")>0,true
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Alejandro - I tried the formula above, but I received an error that it did NOT recognize 'IndexOf'  functions.. It may be the version of SSRS that we are using.. 2005.